# Calculating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x)dx.$ The application of Residue Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ and  $g:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ given by $f(z)=z^2-2az+1, g(z)=z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1$ where $a=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$.

I have to calculate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x)dx$$
where $F(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$

But I have no idea to solve this. Somehow, I think I can use Residue Theorem, but I don't know how.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $g(z)=z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1 = \frac{z^5 + 1}{z + 1}$, from this it follows that $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{(z+1)(z^2−2az+1)}{z^5 + 1} \to 0$ as $|z|\to\infty$. What you can do is integrate over a semi-circle which lies on the real axis of the complex plain. If youdo this and take the limit in the radius of the cirlce($R\to\infty$) you get back the the value of the "real-valued" integral. You will need residue theroem for calculating the integral over the semi-circle on the complex plain.